# Display Oracle transfered bytes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to display Oracle uploaded and downloaded bytes from client applications?

Are there any internal traffic counters?

Answer (score 0):

There are session and system stats:

```
SELECT NAME, VALUE FROM GV$SYSSTAT WHERE NAME IN ('bytes sent via SQL*Net to client', 'bytes received via SQL*Net from client', 'SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client');
```

The values are since the instance started.

Session level view is `GV$SESSTAT`.